# How can I make an iframe reactive

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I have the following shiny app that renders a pdf located in the www directory using an iframe:

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("PDF creator"),
  
  # Sidebar with refresh button
  fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("refresh_btn", "Refresh PDF")
    ),
    
    # Show the PDF
    mainPanel(
      tags$iframe(id="pdf_iframe", style="height:600px; width:100%", src="pdf_file.pdf", seamless = T)
    )
  )
)
```

And server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Some code that rewrites the "pdf_file.pdf" every time the "refresh button is pressed
  
}
```

How can I make the rendered PDF reactive? Now, when the "pdf_file.pdf" is rewritten after the "refresh" button is pressed, the shown pdf remains unchanged, even though "pdf_file.pdf" does change when it is opened manually or the shiny app is restarted

Comment: You’ve omitted the server code that is central to your question. Render the `iframe` using `uiOutput` and `renderUI`. Put a dependency on your refresh button (or a reactive containing the uploaded pdf) in the `renderUI`. There are plenty of examples of how to do this, or similar things, on SO.